# Form validation in javascript - minimum characters

Tags: javascript, forms

I need to validate a form and I want every input must have 6 more than characters.

The following script is working for 0 characters.

How do I edit it in order to set a minimum characters limit to 6?

```
<script>
    function validateForm(formId)
    {
        var inputs, index;
        var form=document.getElementById(formId);
        inputs = form.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
            // deal with inputs[index] element.
            if (inputs[index].value==null || inputs[index].value=="")
            {
                alert("Field is empty");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the form:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return validateForm('myForm');" style="margin-bottom:10px;" _lpchecked="1">
    <div id="InputsWrapper">
        <div>
            <input type="text" name="mytext[]" id="field_1" value="http://">
            <a href="#" id="AddMoreFileBox" style="font-size:12px;margin:0 0 0px 0;"><img src="images/plus.png" style="margin-left:10px;height:24px;">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="height:10px;"></div>
    <input type="submit" style="border:none;background-color:#ff9900;padding:10px 30px 10px 
     30px;font-size:24px;font-weight:bold;color:#FFF;" value="CONTINUE">
</form>
```

Comment: `if(inputs[index].value.length <6)`

Comment: please format your html before you post is. using http://jsbeautifier.org/. I format your codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the loop, check the `value` `length`

```
if (inputs[index].value==null || inputs[index].value=="" || inputs[index].value.length < 6) {
    alert("Field is not 6 characters minimum!");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a field has 6 characters using:

```
if (document.forms["name"]["field name"].value < 6).
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest assigning a CSS class ("InputClassName" in this example) to the inputs you want to validate against - and then changing your code to something like this:

```
inputs = form.getElementsByClassName('InputClassName');
 for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
        if (inputs[index].value==null || inputs[index].value=="" || inputs[index].value.length < 6))
        {
            alert("Field must be 6 characters or more");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

The advantage of this approach is that you can add radio buttons or checkboxes WITHOUT the "InputClassName" class - that have values less than 6 characters and your logic will still work.  With the current setup, your logic would break.